# How would I write a regex to take any input string and output only the letters?

Tags: javascript, regex

How would I write a regex to take any input string and output only the letters?

input:

`'This is a sentence. &)$&(@#1232&()$123!!ª•º–ª§∞•¶§¢• This is an example of the input string. '`

output:

`'thisisasentencethisisanexampleoftheinputstring'`

Comment: Is `µ` a letter? How about `é`?

Comment: @muistooshort µ is a micron, éither way I'm looking for standard english alphabet.

Comment: `µ` is actually a lower case Greek letter that is also used as the Metric prefix for 10**-6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove all the non-letters like this:

```
var input = 'This is a sentence. &)$&(@#1232&()$123!!ª•º–ª§∞•¶§¢• This is an example of the input string. ';
var output = input.replace(/[^a-zA-Z]/g, "");
```

If you want the output to be all lowercase, then add `.toLowerCase()` onto the end like this:

```
var output = input.replace(/[^a-zA-Z]/g, "").toLowerCase();
```

By way of explanation, this regex matches all characters that are not `a-z` or `A-Z`.  The `g` flag on the end of the regex tells it to replace all of them in the entire string (not just the first match it finds).  And, the `""` tells it to replace each match with an empty string (effectively removing all the match characters).

Answer (score 2):

```
var text = 'This is a sentence. &)$&(@#1232&()$123!!ª•º–ª§∞•¶§¢• This is an example of the input string. ';
text.replace(/[^a-z]/ig, '');
```